# Envoy Proxy as Explicit proxy

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying to configure Envoy as an explicit proxy to handle connect, tried using config  given at https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/de757584e65da842dee5bddee3893a66b9a6219c/configs/terminate_connect.v3.yaml

is there any example of configuring Envoy as an explicit proxy?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make it work with dynamic forward proxy cluster. Here is the sample config:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 127.0.0.1
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/force-host-rewrite"
                route:
                  cluster: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
                typed_per_filter_config:
                  envoy.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy.v3.PerRouteConfig
                    host_rewrite_literal: www.example.org
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
              - match:
                  connect_matcher:
                    {}
                route:
                  cluster: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
                  upgrade_configs:
                    - upgrade_type: CONNECT
                      connect_config:
                        {}
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.dynamic_forward_proxy.v2alpha.FilterConfig
              dns_cache_config:
                name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cache_config
                dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
    connect_timeout: 1s
    lb_policy: CLUSTER_PROVIDED
    cluster_type:
      name: envoy.clusters.dynamic_forward_proxy
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.clusters.dynamic_forward_proxy.v3.ClusterConfig
        dns_cache_config:
          name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cache_config
          dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Should there be a matcher for websocket `upgrade_type` too?

Comment: Websocket upgrade also works fine. I use it to make avoid Enovy run its state machine on the HTTP traffic after tcp tunnel is established for cleartext traffic.